# What function do I need to use here?

Tags: python

So this is for homework but I have the program pretty much entirley worked out I'm just not sure what function i need to use for this last part.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open("flu_data.csv", "r")
    for line in f:
        try:
            line = line.split(",")
            y = line[2]
            if "48" <= y <= "8":
                x = line[10]
                c = (int(x))
                a = line[8]
                b = (int(a)/int(x))
                print("for week:", y , "of year", line[1], "the number of patients with the flu was", c,
                      "the percentage of elderly patients was", b)
                print("the week with the most flu cases was", y , "with" ?)
        except:
            print("problem with:", line)
    f.close()
```

What I'm trying to do here is get it to print the greatest x value is but I'm not sure which function actually does that when referencing the file. All I need to know is what function do I use here.

Comment: If you were to store all the `x` values in a list, then the `max()` function could tell you the largest value.

Comment: btw I'm not sure that `if "48" <= y <= "8":` is doing what you think its doing.

Comment: Create a variable `max_x = ""`. Every time through the loop, compare `x` to `max_x`. If it's larger, replace `max_x` with `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compute the maximum until you've collected all of the data.  Once you've done that, use the `max` function.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open("flu_data.csv", "r")
    cases_by_week = {}
    for line in f:
        try:
            cols = line.split(",")
            year = cols[1]
            week = cols[2]
            elderly_patients = int(cols[8])
            total_patients = int(cols[10])
            if "48" <= week <= "8":
                cases_by_week[week] = total_patients
                elderly_pct = elderly_patients / total_patients
                print(
                    f"for week: {week} of year {year} the number of "
                    f"patients with the flu was {total_patients} "
                    f"the percentage of elderly patients was {elderly_pct}"
                )
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"skipping line '{line}': {e}")
    f.close()
    max_cases = max(cases_by_week, key=cases_by_week.get)
    print(
        f"the week with the most flu cases was {max_cases} "
        f"with {cases_by_week[max_cases]}"
    )
```